# Когда нажимаю на кнопки, то не выводит: верно или неверно, кнопки просто не убираются, а ответ не выводит. Что я не так написал?

Tags: python, telebot

#Не судите строго :3. Начал учить питон недели 2 назад(

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['play'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("15")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("32")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("50")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько будет 25+25?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def func(message):
    if (message.text == 50):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')

    elif (message.text == 32):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно')

    elif (message.text == 15):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте объявление клавы вывести за пределы функции start,в начало проги и вне всех функций. Вот примерно таким будет код и не забывайте объявлять библиотеки:

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("15")
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("32")
btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("50")
markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['play'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько будет 25+25?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def func(message):
    if (message.text == 50):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')

    elif (message.text == 32):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно')

    elif (message.text == 15):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно')
```

Думаю такое происходит так как кнопки активируются только при выполнении функции start.

Comment: Вынес в начало после токена, но опять та же история. Кнопки остаются после нажатия, а ответ не выводит.

Comment: @Vladiryao Вам нужно все числа в условии поместить в кавычки, взамен 15 - "15" и т.д. Если говорить простым языком это происходит из за того что числа в сообщении имеют текстовый формат(String) , а в условии цифровой(int)

Comment: Ура, спасибо большое)!Только он выдает ответ, но кнопки не убираются. Это надо в конце какую-то команду ввести? ИЛи просто продолжить писать следующие строки и кнопки уберутся сами.

Comment: Я смог это решить, спасибо за ответы)